# Why is list emptying itself between events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, eventhandler

I'm using a List<> as a container for some data returned from database, like this:

```
List<BookInfo> result {get;set;}

protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            result = (new BookInfo()).Search(TextBox1.Text);
            ListView1.DataSource = result;
            ListView1.DataBind();

        }

    }
```

Everything works ok. But when I'm trying to sort this List in other event like this one, it's empty.

```
protected void ListView1_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        IComparer<BookInfo> comparer = new BookInfoOrdering();
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Sort(comparer);

        }
        ListView1.DataSource = result;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I'd just like to know why is it happening. One solution is to call the search method and get the data again but isn't it unnecessary?

Comment: What's the scope of result ? There's not really enough info here to see any obvious issues

Comment: Most likely I'd guess this is happening on two separate postbacks, and `result` isn't being (re)populated the second time.

Comment: Show the Page_Load code....

Comment: Ok, it's obviously a postback issue. Is there a way to populate `result`between postbacks? I assume it would be a bit faster than getting the data fom DB again..

Comment: Depending on how many users are going to concurrently use your website, you could store the list in session, but there are better alternatives to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were trapped by the same trap that many people are trapped by many times - it's the page lifecycle. ASP.NET fools you by pretending that you had one environment including server and browser, but that's not the case. HTTP is state-less. If you need to persist state between two requests, you have several options:

- Serialize the state into the so-called `ViewState` such as to send it to the browser and post it back to the server
- Save it in a database
- Save it in the session
- Introduce caching for the data that need to be retrieved, that is, sequential calls to `BookInfo.Search` with equal parameter values don't issue a new database request (or whatever else is required to get the data)

Comment: @Jan.What kind of answer exactly are you expecting then? I can't tell you whether you should favor ViewState, Session, or database - it is a design choice that only you can make.

Comment: @Jan - then you probably need to rephrase your question. Currently it reads "why is list emptying itself?" and "I'd just like to know what's happending." I responded to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

This would work in a desktop application, but not a asp.net website. Server side data retrieved from one postbacks is not stored for the next postback.

There are several methods for storing data between postbacks. For example using the Session State of the website:

```
// storing
HttpContext.Current.Session["list"] = result;
// retrieving
List<BookInfo> temp = (List<BookInfo>)HttpContext.Current.Session["list"];
```

you should also be able to retrieve the list from the ListView where it was bound.

```
 IComparer<BookInfo> comparer = new BookInfoOrdering();
 List<BookInfo> temp = (List<BookInfo>)ListView1.DataSource;
 temp.Sort(comparer);
 ListView1.DataSource = temp;
 ListView1.DataBind();
```